# Move tag after commit on specified branch

Tags: git

I have a tag, that points on commit in branch.

This tag must be only in that branch.

Is it possible to make after commit hook, that will move tag's pointer to fresh commit, if this commit in specified branch?

Comment: As a rule, you shouldn't move tags and certainly not as part of a normal workflow. When you make a commit on a branch, the branch ref is updated to point to the new commit; what's wrong with using the branch ref?

Comment: I can explain. Name of tag will not change in future, but name of branches can change and i even don't know what branch it will be. So I can say our release manager to checkout tag 'major_release'.

Comment: Why not have `major_release` as a branch or symbolic-ref to the current branch?

Answer (score 0):

You can move the tag:

```
git tag -a -f yourTag
```

But that means

```
git push origin :refs/tag/yourTag # delete it on the remote
                                  # if you already pushed it
git push origin master --tags
```

Comment: This is a really bad idea (IMHO) because once the tag has been fetched by any client, that client will refuse to update the tag reference. Tags are not the right tool for this scenario.

Comment: @CharlesBailey I agree. I am not sure exactly what the OP's scenario exactly is though.